# Using BusyBox version of netcat for listening tcp port

Tags: linux, listener, port, netcat, busybox

I need to listen some arbitrary port inside the Linux embedded box.
I chose port 6660 because it is meant for uncrypted connections anyway and since the Linux box running customized Linux OS there are not many ports open.
I found out that netcat (nc on command line) would be the easiest and the best ready to go solution for that, so I do not have to start programming some C program for that purpose.

I managed to grasp the command and options and I implemented simplest way to listen plain text on my PC from another PC like this:

```
sven@sven:~$ nc 192.168.4.110 6660
sven@sven:~$ hello there!
anotherUser@userg:~$ nc -l -p 6660
anotherUser@userg:~$ hello there!
```

But the case is that the netcat tool is coming with the busybox package on that Linux box. And I am not sure what would be the syntax how to listen a port (6660 for example). I always get the same dialog:

```
~ # nc -l -p 6660
BusyBox v1.17.1 (Debian 1:1.17.1-8) multi-call binary.
Usage: nc [IPADDR PORT]    
Open a pipe to IP:PORT
```

Also I've tried many other ways how to implement listening but cant get it done.
I assume at least it would give me any options? also

```
nc -h
```

or

```
nc --help
```

dont give any "minus" options

But sending the text from Linux embedded box to my PC works:

```
~ # nc 192.168.4.130 6660
fsdf
tere
^C
~ #
sven@sven:~$ nc -l -p 6660
fsdf
tere
```

Linux embedded box has fully functional net connection inside the same local network and has existing eth0 and lo links

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:E3:47:00:03:5F  
          inet addr:192.168.4.179  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28046281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:428464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2458890234 (2.2 GiB)  TX bytes:83021395 (79.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:444956 (434.5 KiB)  TX bytes:444956 (434.5 KiB)
```

Töövõite!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Here's the manual page for busybox's nc implementation](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#nc).

The correct syntax is

```
nc -l -p <port>
```

The issue is, I think, that your version of busybox is compiled without nc listening capabilities. Indeed there's a config option at build time, `NC_SERVER`, that needs to be enabled to turn that feature on.

Can you build another `nc`, perhaps from [this version](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/), and copy the binary onto your embedded host? You may need to build a cross-compiler environment.